# Sigma Notation in Julia

Tags: julia

I am having trouble understanding how to solve summation notation in Julia. I have the parts in parenthesis figured out, but do not know how to calculate the summation part. My problem looks something like this:

```
100
 ∑  (4n^x + 4/n)
n=1
```

Is there a built in function or a way for me to code the summation part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example:

```
f(x) = sum(4n^x + 4/n for n in 1:100)
```